# SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe: How to specify sonar.sources?

Tags: sonarqube

I have a broad source tree and I want to analyze only some directories in the tree. In SonarQube documentation I have found description of 
`sonar.sources` option which should help in this case.

First I have tried to send it in as a command-line parameter `/d:sonar.source=`... The `SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin` call accepts the parameter, but it doesn't make any difference. The `SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end` call doesn't accept the parameter.

I have also tried to specify it in the config file `SonarQube.Analysis.xml` and it doesn't make any difference either (while `sonar.exclusions` works very well through the config file).

SonarQube's `Administration > Analysis Scope` web-page doesn't have `sonar.sources`.

Is there any way to make `sonar.sources` work together with `SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe`?

I use `sonar-scanner-msbuild-3.0.0.629`and `SonarQube 6.4`.

Answer (score 2):

The SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild will automatically detect and include sources based on your solution file. Instead of trying to narrow analysis to a subset via `sonar.sources`, allow the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild to do its normal discovery job and [narrow analysis scope](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreFiles) instead using exclusions. Specifically, set `sonar.exclusions` (Project **Administration > Analysis Scope > Files**) to omit the files/directories you want to skip.

Alternately, you could use `sonar.inclusions` (found at roughly the same spot in the interface) to narrow analysis to only the files you want analyzed. That may be easier if "include" is a smaller subset than "exclude". However, you should only use one or the other of these two settings.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! have a really broad sources tree and I'm interested only in a few sub-directories. Therefore my `

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have a really broad sources tree and I'm interested only in a few sub-directories. Therefore my `sonar.exclusions` list will be very long. Is it possible to combine `sonar.exclusions` with `sonar.inclusions`? I have included the directories I were interested in into `sonar.inclusions` and excluded auto-generated files `sonar.exclusions`. It didn't work well - I got empty analysis in the end, despite I got non-zero entries in the 'NN files indexed' (in  directories I have excluded). Do the inclusion rules use base or working directories?

Comment: See my expansion @olegg.

Comment: Thank you, @g-ann-sonarsource-team! I have tested the `sonar.exclusions` on a toy project and it works. On my real project I will end up with a list of 40+ exclusions, I hope SQ will be able to handle it. Therefore I would prefer a working combination of inclusions and exclusions - it would result in much shorter an more manageable configuration.

Comment: I have found that the `sonar.exclusions` works only _within_ a _project_ instead of the entire solution. If you have a solution with a number of sub-directories which contain other projects, there is no way to exclude the sub-directories with `sonar.exclusions`. What can I use to exclude the sub-directories?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam: Do you have any update on why we can only use folder/file structures inside projects? Which part of the system is the limiting factor?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `sonar.exclusions` only work within a project, meaning that any matches only work on files/folders inside a project structure. This in turn means we cannot limit entire projects as far as I know. Instead, we need to come up with some other option.

One is to name each test file according to some pattern that is NOT used by files we actually want to analyze, for example `*Tests.cs`

This would mean we could use `sonar.exclusions=**/*Tests.cs`

Another way would be to put all source files in test projects in sub-directories mating some pattern, again a pattern that is NOT used by projects/files we want to analyze. For example `my-project/tests/stuff.cs`

Use `sonar.exclusions=tests/**/*`

All-in-all I find this behaviour very annoying - being able to exclude entire folders/projects is much more useful. Having to rely on conventions will break sooner or later and requires more maintenance and knowledge.

Tested with `Sonar 6.7.1 (build 35068)`, `MSBuild Scanner 4.0.2` and `SonarC# 6.7 (build 4267)`